# Is correct to change Date type to Java 8 LocalDate in JPA Entities?

Tags: java-8

For example change this:

```
@Entity
public class Person {   
    @Past
    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    @Column(name = "birth_date", length = ConstantNumeric.TWENTY_FIVE)
    private Date birthDate;
...
}
```

To this:

```
@Entity
public class Person {   
    @Past
    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    @Column(name = "birth_date", length = ConstantNumeric.TWENTY_FIVE)
    private LocalDate birthDate;
...
}
```

This is correct way to a Java 8 project? Or it's better to convert the LocalDate to Date when needed?

Comment: No, both types are TOTALLY different. `java.util.Date` is a unix-like global timestamp, while `java.time.LocalDate` is just a plain date without any reference to a timezone. And JPA does not support the new Java-8-time library yet.

Answer (score 3):

I'm aware that this questions is old, but I will give an answer anyway.

As of JPA 2.1, you can use `AttributConverter`s as explained [here](http://www.adam-bien.com/roller/abien/entry/new_java_8_date_and). Simply put, you have to implement `javax.persistence.AttributeConverter<LocalDate, Date>` to convert from a `LocalDate` to `Date` and vice versa.
Then you can use attributes of type `LocalDate` directly in JPA entities.

Comment: Please elaborate your answer for that it is not near a link-only answer. [answer]